# Can't send data through UART using HAL_UART_Receive_IT

Tags: stm32, freertos, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, cmsis

I am using stm32f4 on discovery board with freertos running on it.

Just started working with stm32 controller and trying to make data transfer using UART. `Printf` based on `HAL_UART_Transmit` works perfectly, but receiving data isn't working.

According to numerous tutorials it should be very simple. I create a project in Stm32CubeMX, add all necessary stuff (freertos, USART3, NVIC), enable USART3 global interrupt and generate the code.

I'm trying to add `HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3, &rx_char, 1);` or something similar in a task and it doesn't do anything. I suppose it flies through it very fast and doesn't wait for characters to be sent from the terminal.

What do I miss here?

Comment: You'll have to re-enable the interrupt each time you receive the char. Don't use HAL for this. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297318/cannot-transmit-every-characters-through-uart/37323052#37323052](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297318/cannot-transmit-every-characters-through-uart/37323052#37323052).

Comment: @PauloSoares i have `__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart3, UART_IT_RXNE)` in main. But actually my program never gets to `USART3_IRQHandler`. It doesn't matter what's in it because it never happens. Should it be triggered at least once when I send something? I am completely lost here.

Comment: @LogenSand did you find the solution for your question??