# STM32 HAL USART receive by interrupt

Tags: stm32, hal

I have some trouble to receive data over the USART. What I actually want to achieve ist, that I can receive a command over USART with no specific length (only a maximum possible length). So I use the interrupt routine to check each character received, but I somehow still cannot achieve what I want. The routine is called each time I receive a new character, but somehow HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1,rx_data,buff_size_rx) does not upgrade in realtime, then I don't see the received character when I check rx_data[pointer], but a few time later it is in the rx_data buffer.

What I have so far:

```c
int pointer =0;

...

void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 0 */
    if ( USART1->ISR & UART_IT_TXE) {

    }

    if ( USART1->ISR & UART_IT_RXNE) {
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1,rx_data,buff_size_rx);
        if(rx_data[pointer]=='\0') {
              pointer=0;
              readCommand(rx_data);
              clearBuffer(rx_data,buff_size_rx);
        } else {
          pointer++;
          if(pointer>=buff_size_rx) {
              pointer=0;
          }
        }
    }
    /* USER CODE END USART1_IRQn 0 */
    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 1 */



  /* USER CODE END USART1_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Comment: what is the point of duplicating the buffer implementation? BTW you cant call HAL_UART_Receive_IT from here and then call HAL irq handler which calls it again. Do it bare registers or HAL not both. Anyway HAL for the simple peripheral like uart?

Comment: What do you mean by dublicating the buffer implementation?  I would like to achieve this in HAL, but I really found no solution yet. DMA would be nice, but there I need a fixed length for each command or use a timeout, which is not supported by HAL for an STM32F303K8T6.

Comment: Hal does it. You should not do anything with the buffet if you use hal. I would implement it bare resister myself but it is your code, without this silly library.  How long your messages are? If short there is no point of DMA.

Comment: Well the messages are only around 16 characters. If I use just HAL_UART_Receive_IT, it will write the characters to the rx_data buffer, but I then never see if I received a null character and it acts like a ring buffer, which only works for a fixed length.

Comment: Have a look at the code I use to receive arbitrary GPS data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297318/cannot-transmit-every-characters-through-uart/37323052#37323052). It uses HAL but shortcuts the interrupt. If I were to do it again I would dump HAL and go with plain CMSIS.

Comment: IMO DMA for 16 bytes is not worth

Comment: @Paulo Soares - bare register, CMSIS is only the bunch of definitions & some inline functions.

Comment: Yep, no libraries.

Answer (score 7):

`HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` is not meant to be called from an interrupt handler that way, but to initiate receiving a **fixed** number of bytes via interrupt.

A possible workaround is to check your input buffer *after* `HAL_UART_IRQHandler()` completes, i.e. in the `/* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 1 */` section. When a command is processed, you can reset `pRxBuffPtr` and `RxXferCount` in the handle structure to their original values to start from the start of the buffer again.

Another <strike>horrible</strike> possible workaround would be to call `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` with a buffer size of 1, and set up a `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback()` handler that checks the received byte each time, and calls `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` again when necessary.

Of course you could do it without HAL, as PeterJ and others (always) suggest.

- You've already implemented pin and interrupt setup, leave them unchanged at first.
- Calculate the `UART->BRR` value according to the reference manual, or copy the relevant code from hal.
- set `UART->CR1=USART_CR1_RE|USART_CR1_TE|USART_CR1_UE|USART_CR1_RXNEIE;` Now, you are getting interrupts.
- In the interrupt function, read `UART->SR` into a temporary variable, and examine it.
- Read `UART->DR` when there is a received byte waiting, do the error handling otherwise (later).
- Get rid of the rest of the HAL calls when the above is working.

Interrupt response and processing time is often *critical* in embedded applications, and the HAL just wastes a lot of that.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the workaround first. But how do you reset pRxBuffPtr and RxXferCount? I mean the pointer needs an adress?

Comment: @berendi **it is called** in the HAL IRQ handler. Did you ever seen how this handler is implemented. This function does the phisical read from the U(S)ART and places the data in the receive buffer. Horrible implementation anyway.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: In which HAL version? I've checked a few versions that are lying around on my drive, but `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` is never called in the `HAL_UART_IRQHandler()`, or anywhere else in the HAL libraries. The actual read of the `USART->DR` register occurs in `UART_Receive_IT()` (without the `HAL_` prefix), which is declared static, not accessible from the user program.

Comment: @HansPeterLoft: set them to the start (that's a pointer) and lenght of your receive buffer.

Answer (score 6):

The normal HAL library is not useful for continuous reception or commands with different length.

If you have the complete HAL package installed, you could look at the examples for the **L**ow**L**evel interface.

```
Projects\STM32F411RE-Nucleo\Examples_LL\USART\USART_Communication_Rx_IT_Continuous
```

The main thing is to set you usart to continuous reception:

```c
    void Configure_USART(void) {    
        /* (1) Enable GPIO clock and configures the USART pins *********************/

        /* Enable the peripheral clock of GPIO Port */
        USARTx_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();

        /* Configure Tx Pin as : Alternate function, High Speed, Push pull, Pull up */
        LL_GPIO_SetPinMode(USARTx_TX_GPIO_PORT, USARTx_TX_PIN, LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE);
        USARTx_SET_TX_GPIO_AF();
        LL_GPIO_SetPinSpeed(USARTx_TX_GPIO_PORT, USARTx_TX_PIN, LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH);
        LL_GPIO_SetPinOutputType(USARTx_TX_GPIO_PORT, USARTx_TX_PIN, LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL);
        LL_GPIO_SetPinPull(USARTx_TX_GPIO_PORT, USARTx_TX_PIN, LL_GPIO_PULL_UP);

        /* Configure Rx Pin as : Alternate function, High Speed, Push pull, Pull up */
        LL_GPIO_SetPinMode(USARTx_RX_GPIO_PORT, USARTx_RX_PIN, LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE);
        USARTx_SET_RX_GPIO_AF();
        LL_GPIO_SetPinSpeed(USARTx_RX_GPIO_PORT, USARTx_RX_PIN, LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH);
        LL_GPIO_SetPinOutputType(USARTx_RX_GPIO_PORT, USARTx_RX_PIN, LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL);
        LL_GPIO_SetPinPull(USARTx_RX_GPIO_PORT, USARTx_RX_PIN, LL_GPIO_PULL_UP);

        /* (2) NVIC Configuration for USART interrupts */
        /*  - Set priority for USARTx_IRQn */
        /*  - Enable USARTx_IRQn */
        NVIC_SetPriority(USARTx_IRQn, 0);  
        NVIC_EnableIRQ(USARTx_IRQn);

        /* (3) Enable USART peripheral clock and clock source ***********************/
        USARTx_CLK_ENABLE();

        /* (4) Configure USART functional parameters ********************************/
        /* TX/RX direction */
        LL_USART_SetTransferDirection(USARTx_INSTANCE, LL_USART_DIRECTION_TX_RX);

        /* 8 data bit, 1 start bit, 1 stop bit, no parity */
        LL_USART_ConfigCharacter(USARTx_INSTANCE, LL_USART_DATAWIDTH_8B, LL_USART_PARITY_NONE, LL_USART_STOPBITS_1);

        /* No Hardware Flow control */
        /* Reset value is LL_USART_HWCONTROL_NONE */
        // LL_USART_SetHWFlowCtrl(USARTx_INSTANCE, LL_USART_HWCONTROL_NONE);

        /* Oversampling by 16 */
        /* Reset value is LL_USART_OVERSAMPLING_16 */
        // LL_USART_SetOverSampling(USARTx_INSTANCE, LL_USART_OVERSAMPLING_16);

        /* Set Baudrate to 115200 using APB frequency set to 100000000/APB_Div Hz */
        /* Frequency available for USART peripheral can also be calculated through LL RCC macro */
        /* Ex :
            Periphclk = LL_RCC_GetUSARTClockFreq(Instance); or 
            LL_RCC_GetUARTClockFreq(Instance); depending on USART/UART instance
  
            In this example, Peripheral Clock is expected to be equal to 
            100000000/APB_Div Hz => equal to SystemCoreClock/APB_Div
        */
        LL_USART_SetBaudRate(USARTx_INSTANCE, SystemCoreClock/APB_Div, LL_USART_OVERSAMPLING_16, 115200); 

        /* (5) Enable USART *********************************************************/
        LL_USART_Enable(USARTx_INSTANCE);
    }
```

The USART IT Handler should look like

```c
    void USARTx_IRQHandler(void)
    {
      /* Check RXNE flag value in SR register */
      if(LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(USARTx_INSTANCE) && LL_USART_IsEnabledIT_RXNE(USARTx_INSTANCE))
      {
        /* RXNE flag will be cleared by reading of DR register (done in call) */
        /* Call function in charge of handling Character reception */
        USART_CharReception_Callback();
      }
      else
      {
        /* Call Error function */
        Error_Callback();
      }
    }
```

The last thing to set up is the Callback

```
void USART_CharReception_Callback(void);
```

Where you could put the bytes into an buffer and handle it in the main loop or where you want.

Answer (score 3):

Since I stumbled over the problem today and could not find a good solution to it, I like to present a very simple one, using most of the HAL but avoiding the problems described...

Short verison of my approach is:

In the last user code section (for the appropriate USART instance, if using more than one) of `void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)`, enable the IRQ with:

```c
__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huartx, UART_IT_RXNE);
```

Then put the desired code in your interrupt function:

```c
void USART3_IRQHandler(void)  {    
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_IRQn 0 */
    CallMyCodeHere();
    return;  // To avoid calling the default HAL handler at all 
             // (in case you want to save the time)
    /* USER CODE END USART3_IRQn 0 */
    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart3);  // This is the CubeMX generated HAL handler
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_IRQn 1 */
    /* USER CODE END USART3_IRQn 1 */ 
}
```

Don't use HAL_UART_Receive_IT anywhere, it will disable the IRQ and you need to re-enable it, if you want to get called with every reception.

The long version could be found in my post [here](https://blog.the78mole.de/stm32-uart-continuous-receive-with-interrupt/)...

Answer (score 3):

Here is the full example of receiving data and idle line detection by interrupts:

1. Enable the receive interrupts and  idle line detection in `main.c`:

```c
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */
  __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart2, UART_IT_RXNE);  // enable receive intterupts 
  __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart2, UART_IT_IDLE);  // enable idle line detection 
  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */
```

2. Sort out the idle line event from within `USARTx_IRQHandler` in `stm32f4xx_it.c`:

```c
void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 0 */
  if (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart2, UART_FLAG_IDLE)) { 
    __HAL_UART_CLEAR_IDLEFLAG(&huart2); // taken from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471272/setting-up-stm32-timer-for-uart-idle-detection#comment1353999_480556
    uart2_idleHandler();
  } else {
    uart2_handler();
  }
  return;
  /* USER CODE END USART2_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 1 */
  /* USER CODE END USART2_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Testing:

1. Create the following handlers:

```c
char my_uart_buffer[256];
int my_uart_buffer_index = 0;

void uart2_handler(void){
  char buff; 
  HAL_UART_Receive (&huart2, (uint8_t *)&buff, 1, 400);
  my_uart_buffer[my_uart_buffer_index++] = buff;
}

void uart2_idleHandler(){
  my_uart_buffer_index = 0; 
}
```

2. Open a serial port client in your PC, setup as 115200 baud, 8N1.
3. Set a breakpoint to `uart2_idleHandler()`.
4. Send "Hello world".
5. You can examine your buffer by `p/c *my_uart_buffer@20` when breakpoint hits.

## Example Project

[Here](https://github.com/ceremcem/modbus_example) is the full example that runs on STM32F407 Discovery board.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work using HAL! It may not be as elegant as other implementations but it is doable.

You have to create an error handler function and then the function that calls the HAL_UART_RCV_IT must flush the UART RX whenever there is an overrun error.

In addition, I work with two buffers. While the Interrupt is filling one buffer the main loop is emptying the other.

Here it how it is working well for me:

```
typedef enum
{
  UARTREADY = 0,
    UARTBUSY  = 1,
    UARTDATA  = 2,
    UARTERROR = 3
} enumUartStatus;

while(1){
    if(UARTREADY == isUsart3RxReady()){

        Usart3RxBuffer((char *)&SOMRxBytesBuffer[use_buffer_index], RCV_BUFFER_BANK_SIZE);   // receive bytes in the raw buffer

        if(use_buffer_index == RCV_BUFFER_BANK1_INDEX){         
            use_buffer_index = RCV_BUFFER_BANK2_INDEX;
            rxb1_stats++;
        }else{  
            use_buffer_index = RCV_BUFFER_BANK1_INDEX;
            rxb2_stats++;
        }

    }
}

void HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if(huart == NULL){
        return;
    }

    if(huart->Instance == USART3){

        if(HAL_UART_GetError(huart) == HAL_UART_ERROR_FE){
            Usart3Ready = UARTREADY;
        }else{      
            Usart3Ready = UARTERROR;
        }
    }
}

void Usart3RxBuffer(char *buffer, unsigned short rxbuffersize){
  /* Reset transmission flag */

    if(Usart3Ready != UARTREADY)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(HAL_UART_GetState(&huart3) == HAL_UART_STATE_READY){

        /*##-3- Put UART peripheral in reception process ###########################*/
        if (HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3, (uint8_t *)buffer, rxbuffersize) != HAL_OK)
        {
            // TODO: Error_Handler();
            DEBUG_TRACE(DEBUG_MSK_MAIN, "UART3 error starting receiver!\r\n");
        }else{

            // An interrupt HAL_UART_ErrorCallback hit right here !!!!
            // There is an overrun error happening here so we have to retry
            // this is because we are using the Receive_IT in a continous communication and there is no handshake or flow control
            if(Usart3Ready != UARTERROR){
                /* Busy waiting to receive bytes */
                Usart3Ready = UARTBUSY;
            }
        }
    }

    if(Usart3Ready == UARTERROR){
        HAL_UART_AbortReceive_IT(&huart3);
        Usart3Ready = UARTREADY;
    }
}
```