# STM32 Failed to Receive data with HAL_UART_Recceive_IT

Tags: c, stm32, uart, stm32f4, nucleo

I'm beginer in STM32, i have a project and need to receive data from another device like arduino, and now I try transmit data from UART 3 and I receive data with UART 1. but I can't get any data. I connect TX uart 3 to RX uart 1 and TX uart 1 to RX uart 3.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
int i = 0;
char bufferReceive[6], bufferTransmit[10];

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (huart->Instance == USART1)  //current UART
        {
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t*)bufferReceive, 1);   //activate UART receive interrupt every time
        }
}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{
 HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t*)bufferReceive, 1);
 while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */`enter code here`


     sprintf(bufferTransmit,"%d\n",i);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)bufferTransmit, sizeof(bufferTransmit), 1000);
                    HAL_Delay(500);

                    i++;

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198829/stm32-hal-usart-receive-by-interrupt

Answer (score 0):

First thing your code is messy and hard to read.

Second, you are missing your entire initialization region before `while(1)` so your system shouldn't be doing anything.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
int i = 0;
char bufferReceive[6], bufferTransmit[10];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (huart->Instance == USART1)
    {
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t*)bufferReceive, 1);
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */


    /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART3_UART_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t*)bufferReceive, 1);
    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1)
    {
        sprintf(bufferTransmit,"%d\n",i);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)bufferTransmit, sizeof(bufferTransmit), 1000);
        HAL_Delay(500);
        i++;
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */
        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

You are receiving one byte at `HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t*)bufferReceive, 1);`.

Which does not wait it simply moves onward.

Next, you transmit `bufferTransmit` which then causes UART1 to receive one byte and continues to receive all bytes one by one in the same memory location.

It seems you are not using `i` properly as you probably want something like `HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t*)&bufferReceive[i], 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize anything. Peripherals, pins, clocks etc have to be set up before they can work.